# Custom form Filed using cleaning/validation in field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django custom form field:

```
 class RichTextFormField(forms.fields.CharField):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Create a new WYSIWYG form field.
            """
            kwargs.update({
                'widget': CustomTextWidget()
            })
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know I can do clean after in the form, but I want to do some cleaning (if is possible) directly on the field(because I will repeat this field multiple times.

I want to do a min-length if the attribute is available, and also an html clean.

I don't know what method to overwrite and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `clean(self, value)` method:

```
def clean(self, value):
    # first let the superclass run the validators
    value = super().clean(value)
    # your validation goes here
    return value
```